# How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?

Tags: c++, gcc, character-encoding, g++

I'm trying to compile a [UTF-16BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) C++ source file in g++ with the -finput-charset compiler option, but I'm always getting a bunch of errors.  More details follow.

### My environment (in [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) Linux):

- g++: 4.1.2
- [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv): 2.5
- Linux language (in Terminal): LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

### My sample source file (stored in UTF-16BE encoding):

```
// main.cpp:

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, UTF-16" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### My steps:

- **I read the manual of g++ about the -finput-charset option.**  The g++ manual says:

> **-finput-charset=charset**
> Set the input character set, used for translation from the character set of the input file to the source character set used by
> GCC.  If the locale does not specify, or GCC cannot get this
> information from the locale, **the default is UTF-8**.  This can be
> overridden by either the locale or this command line option.
> Currently the command line option takes precedence if there’s a
> conflict.  charset can be any encoding supported by the system’s
> "**iconv**" library routine.

- **Thus I entered the command as follows:**

> g++ -finput-charset=UTF-16BE main.cpp

and I got these errors:

> In file included from main.cpp:1:
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iostream:1:
> error: stray ‘\342’ in program
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iostream:1:
> error: stray ‘\274’ in program
>
> ...(repeatedly, A LOT, around 4000+)...
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iostream:1:
> error: stray ‘\257’ in program
>
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cpp:5: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
>
> main.cpp:5: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’

- **The manual text suggests that the charset can be any encoding supported by 'iconv' routine, thus I guessed the compilation errors might be caused by my iconv library.  I then tested the iconv:**

> iconv --from-code=UTF-16BE --to-code=UTF-8 --output=main_utf8.cpp main.cpp

A "main_utf8.cpp" file is generated as expected.  I then tried to compile it:

> g++ -finput-charset=UTF-8 main_utf8.cpp

Note that I specified the input-charset explicitly to see if I did anything wrong, but this time a "a.out" was generated without any errors.  When I ran it, it could produce the correct output.

### Finally...

Where did I go wrong?

### Further edits:

Some updates:

1. When I said "UTF-16" I meant "UTF-16 + [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)".  In fact I used UTF-16BE.  I have updated the text above.
2. Some answers say the errors are caused by the non-UTF-16 header files.  Here are my thoughts if this is the case: We'll always include some standard header files when writing a C/C++ project, right?  Such as stdio.h or iostream.  If the G++ compiler only deals with the encoding of the source files created by us but never with the source files in the standard library, then what does this -finput-charset option exist for?

### Final edit:

At last, my solution is like this:

1. At the beginning, I changed the encoding of my source files to [GB 2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312), as "Mr Lister" said below.  This worked fine for a while, but later I found it not suitable for my situation because most of the other parts in the system still use UTF-8 for communication and interfaces, thus I must convert the encoding in many places... Not only an overhead of my work, it may also result in some performance decrease in my program.
2. Later I tried to convert all my source files to UTF-8 + BOM.  In this way, Visual Studio in Windows could compile them happily but GCC in Linux would complain.  I then wrote a shell script to remove the BOM, and before I want to compile my code with GCC, I run this script first.
3. Luckily, I don't have to build the code in Linux manually because [TeamCity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) the continuous integration tool is used in my project to generate the build automatically.  I could change the build steps in TeamCity to help me run this script before the daily build starts.
4. With this UTF-8 + BOM + script method, I decide not to edit my source code in Linux, because if I want to do so, I must make sure my code could build successfully before I commit it, which means I must run the script to remove the BOM before I build the code, which means [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) would report *every* file is modified (BOM removed) thus make it very easy to mistakenly commit a wrong file.  To solve this problem, I wrote another shell script to add the BOM back to the source files.  Though I still don't edit my code very often in Linux, but when I really need to, I don't have to face the terribly long change list in the commit dialog.

Comment: Why not just convert the source file to UTF-8? There is really no good reason to ever use UTF-16 for anything.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Agree.  Actually the code in my question is merely a simple example.  In my project there are a lot of Chinese strings and comments, and we plan to build everything in both Linux and Windows.  But you know, Linux doesn't recognize UTF-8+BOM and Windows requires the BOM, thus I'm trying to find something neutrally, such as UTF-16 or GBK.

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM should work perfectly on any platform. If the compiler you have on Windows doesn't support UTF-8 without BOM, it's time to look for a compliant compiler. UTF-8+BOM is heresy.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Sorry I didn't mention it clearly.  We use Visual Studio 2008 to compile the code.  Visual Studio 2008 doesn't seem to work perfectly with UTF-8 without BOM..

Comment: Then don't use VS2k8 to compile, but a sane compiler; or cross-compile from Linux. The problem here isn't the text encoding, it's bad tools.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but my g++ says it has more command line switches: `--encoding`, `-fexec-charset` and `-fwide-exec-charset`. I don't know what these do exactly, but maybe they're worth checking out.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: "Then don't use VS2k8 to compile" Why do people keep suggesting things that obviously *can't* just happen?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm not sure I follow you? How is that something that can't just happen? If you have a broken tool, throw it away. That's pretty much a no-brainer in my book.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: "Broken" is a matter of perspective. You value reading UTF-8 without BOMs. Other people value tools for other reasons. And some people work for other people who have needs that *require* certain tools, regardless of how "broken" they might be in some manor. My point is that just because *you* think it should be thrown away doesn't mean that he has that desire or *option*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: He's already compiling on Linux with g++, so not using VS2k8 is clearly an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Encoding Blues

You cannot use UTF-16 for source code files; because the header you are including, `<iostream>`, is not UTF-16-encoded. As `#include` includes the files verbatim, this means that you suddenly have an UTF-16-encoded file with a large chunk (approximately 4k, apparently) of invalid data.

There is almost no good reason to ever use UTF-16 for anything, so this is just as well.

Regarding problems with encoding support: The OSes themselves are not responsible for providing encoding support; this comes down to the compilers used.

g++ on Windows supports absolutely all of the same encodings as g++ on Linux, because it's the same program, unless whatever version of g++ you are using on Windows relies on a deeply broken iconv library.

Inspect your toolchain and ensure that all your tools are in working order.

As an alternative; don't use Chinese in the source files, but write them in English, using English-language literals, or simple `TOKEN_STYLE_PLACEHOLDER`s, using `l10n` and `i18n` to replace these in the running executable.

`-finput-charset` is almost certainly a holdover from the days of [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) and other nonsense of the kind; however; an [ISO-8859-n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) file will almost always be compatible with UTF-8 standard headers.

For the next time; remember a simple mantra: "N'DUUH!"; "Never Don't Use UTF-8!"

---

### I18N

A common solution to this kind of problem is to remove the problem entirely, by way of, for instance, [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html).

When using gettext, you usually end up with a function `loc(char *)` that abstracts away most of the translation tool specific code. So, instead of

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::cout << "瓜田李下" << std::endl;
}
```

You would have

```
#include <iostream>

#include "translation.h"

int main () {
  std::cout << loc("DEEPER_MEANING") << std::endl;
}
```

and, in `zh.po`:

```
msgid DEEPER_MEANING
msgstr "瓜田李下"
```

Of course, you could also then have a `en.po`:

```
msgid DEEPER_MEANING
msgstr "Still waters run deep"
```

This can be expanded upon, and the gettext package has tools for expansion of strings with variables and such, or you could use `printf`, to account for different grammars.

---

### The Third Option

Instead of having to deal with multiple compilers with different requirements for file encodings, file endings, byte order marks, and other problems of the kind; it is possible to cross-compile using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) or similar tools.

This option requires some setup, but it may very well reduce future overhead and headaches.

Comment: You're right in this case, but I have yet to see compelling evidence that UTF-16 is always bad. The reasons that are given are always bad too! See also the OP's comment to the question. How would you solve that?

Comment: @MrLister: Well, UTF-16 isn't *always* bad; but for any text consisting of mostly 0-127 (ASCII) it results in a file that is much larger than it needs to be; which makes it especially bad when used for HTML, which is often transmitted over the net. Besides that, using UTF-16 requires working with wide characters and wide character strings, which means working with two character types in most cases, which means added complexity, which means more bugs. Finally, UTF-16 allows the assumption-laden creation of a multibyte text file without a byte order mark, which is obviously bad.

Comment: Of course, but for every argument you give, I could give counter-arguments. Files made of of mostly codepoints above U+0800 are larger in UTF-8 than in UTF-16. This question is not about HTML. You can use only wide characters if you want. Etc. Anyway, this is not about bickering over encodings, let's try to help the OP solve the problem.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Could you give me some more info on the "TOKEN_STYLE_PLACEHOLDER" plus l10n and i18n??  Is this a technique to produce programs that have good i18n characteristics? I'm really new to these stuff because my previou project was all about English, without anything of CJK..

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Finally, I come back to the UTF-8 solution.

Comment: Hmm, what does "Never Don't Use" mean? Is it "never use" or "never fail to use"?

Comment: @Ruslan: "Never fail to use." The double negative is bad form, I know, but it's there got give the acronym the desired form.

Comment: **−1** "You cannot use UTF-16 for source code files; because the header you are including, <iostream>, is not UTF-16-encoded." This is missing an "with g++". Otherwise, as a general statement that's nonsense. For example, Visual C++ has no problem that way.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says the problem is in the *include files,* so I presume what happens is that the include files are normal UTF-8, but the compiler wants to treat them as UTF-16 because of the compiler switch.

So I'm afraid the solution is to always convert the source to UTF-8 first; perhaps in the makefile. Or to find a solution that doesn't contain include files in other encodings...

Maybe a [GB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312) encoding would work, if and only if none of the system source files contain any non-ASCII characters. Then you could tell the compiler they were GB encoded without problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of using GB, which really solved my problem for a while.  After I changed my source files to GB(GB2312, to be exact), they could be built successfully both by GCC and VS2008.  However, I later found it not a good idea in MY situation because most of the other parts in the system still use UTF-8, thus I must convert the encoding everywhere..  Finally I chose to "encode the source files in UTF-8 + BOM so VS2008 could compile them, then use a shell script to remove the BOM before compiling in GCC".  But anyway, your answer really helped me!  Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the compiler will also try to read the header files as UTF-16, which they are not.

Answer (score -1):

UTF-16 is *not* an encoding for bytes. It's an encoding where your basic storage unit is 16 bits large.

When you want to store UTF-16 in a byte sequence you have to choose between UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE.

Comment: Or it could be UTF-16+BOM; which is usually what UTF-16 is held to mean, if it's not held to mean "whatever byte-order is usually used on this platform".