# Build GMP on Windows 32-Bit

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw, 32-bit, gmp

I am trying to compile [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library), because I need it for a Perl module. I have to install everything manually because the machine doesn’t have access to the Internet. I ran configure and used this command in [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) in the GMP Folder:

```
./configure --prefix=C:\gmp --disable-static --enable-shared
```

Now that also worked without problems and created the [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile) now when I run *make* this happens:

```
make
```

Output:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-fac.c' || echo './'`gen-fac.c -o gen-fac.exe
./gen-fac 32 0 >fac_table.h || (rm -f fac_table.h; exit 1)
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-fib.c' || echo './'`gen-fib.c -o gen-fib.exe
./gen-fib header 32 0 >fib_table.h || (rm -f fib_table.h; exit 1)
./gen-fib table 32 0 >mpn/fib_table.c || (rm -f mpn/fib_table.c; exit 1)
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-bases.c' || echo './'`gen-bases.c -o gen-bases.exe -lm
./gen-bases header 32 0 >mp_bases.h || (rm -f mp_bases.h; exit 1)
./gen-bases table 32 0 >mpn/mp_bases.c || (rm -f mpn/mp_bases.c; exit 1)
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-trialdivtab.c' || echo './'`gen-trialdivtab.c -o gen-trialdivtab.exe -lm
./gen-trialdivtab 32 8000 >trialdivtab.h || (rm -f trialdivtab.h; exit 1)
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-jacobitab.c' || echo './'`gen-jacobitab.c -o gen-jacobitab.exe
./gen-jacobitab >mpn/jacobitab.h || (rm -f mpn/jacobitab.h; exit 1)
gcc -std=gnu99 `test -f 'gen-psqr.c' || echo './'`gen-psqr.c -o gen-psqr.exe -lm
./gen-psqr 32 0 >mpn/perfsqr.h || (rm -f mpn/perfsqr.h; exit 1)
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all-am« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests'
Making all in devel
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/devel'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/devel'
Making all in mpn
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpn'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpn'
Making all in mpz
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpz'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpz'
Making all in mpq
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpq'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpq'
Making all in mpf
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpf'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/mpf'
Making all in rand
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/rand'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/rand'
Making all in misc
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/misc'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/misc'
Making all in cxx
make[3]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/cxx'
make[3]: Für das Ziel »all« ist nichts zu tun.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests/cxx'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/tests'
Making all in mpn
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/mpn'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I..  -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`     -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -c fib_table.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/fib_table.o
In file included from ../gmp-impl.h:134:0,
                 from fib_table.c:4:
../gmp-mparam.h:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '!' token
../gmp-mparam.h:1:1: error: stray '\377' in program
../gmp-mparam.h:1:1: error: stray '\376' in program
../gmp-mparam.h:1:14: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:16: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:18: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:20: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:22: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:24: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:26: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:28: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:30: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:32: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:34: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:36: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:38: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:40: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:42: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:44: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:46: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:48: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:50: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:52: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:54: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:56: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:58: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:60: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:62: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:64: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:66: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:68: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
../gmp-mparam.h:1:70: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
In file included from ../gmp-impl.h:144:0,
                 from fib_table.c:4:
e:\fagprogramme\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/inttypes.h:272:1: error: unknown type name 'wchar_t'
e:\fagprogramme\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/inttypes.h:273:29: error: unknown type name 'wchar_t'
e:\fagprogramme\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/inttypes.h:274:1: error: unknown type name 'wchar_t'
e:\fagprogramme\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/inttypes.h:275:9: error: unknown type name 'wchar_t'
Makefile:389: recipe for target `fib_table.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [fib_table.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp/mpn'
Makefile:833: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/e/FAGProgramme/Perl Modules/gmp'
Makefile:656: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What should I do? I also tried it without any parameters, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I fixed some error by installing gcc-core, gcc-g++ to cygwin but still same error at end.

Comment: Stray error doublet \377 \376 (octal. Hexadecimal 0xFF 0xFE) in the beginning of the file is a signature for a UTF-16 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ([UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) (little-endian)). The null characters are consistent with [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding.

Comment: Related (though a different kind of stray errors): *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*

Comment: The canonical question may be *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com)*. Or some of its "Linked" questions (right-hand side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched to Strawberry Perl and used this Tutorial, that was the solution:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/

Answer (score 2):

Open up a Cygwin terminal, create a little text file called `hello.txt` and put some small amount of text in it, and then perform this command:

```
ln -s hello.txt link.txt
```

Now, `cat link.txt` will show your text. However, if you go into Windows, open up Notebook and open `link.txt from` there, you will see some very strange characters. You might see "`hello.txt`". Or nothing.

The reason for this is that Cygwin's *[ln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix))* command creates a kind of fake link that only Cygwin knows how to handle. Windows and Windows programs do not know that this is a Cygwin link, so they just open up the file and see the fake stuff Cygwin put there.

Now, if you look at the command that failed:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I..  -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`     -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -c fib_table.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/fib_table.o
```

You'll see that libtool is running GCC, and GCC must try at some point to open `gmp-mparam.h`, **which is a link**. Because it reads it as garbage instead of what `gmp-mparam.h` is linked to, this must mean that GCC is using some Windows library to read files. And so, GCC fails.

This link was created by `config.status` when you ran `configure`.

Now, do this:

```
rm link.txt
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks
ln -s hello.txt link.txt
```

Now both `cat link.txt` *and* Notebook should both show the contents of `hello.txt`. The reason is that setting `CYGWIN=winsymlinks` tells Cygwin to create Windows link files. Read more about Cygwin links in [Chapter 3 of the Cygwin User's Guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks).

Now that the `CYGWIN` [environment variable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/environment_variable#Noun) is set, run *configure* again, and it will recreate the links using "proper" Windows link files.

Any errors other than the `error: stray '\377' in program` issue has other causes.

Comment: It could be, but \377 \376 in the beginning of the file is a signature for [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) (little-endian). The null characters are consistent with [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding (of a text file).

Comment: What is *"Notebook"*? Do you mean [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad)? (Or perhaps [OneNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote) or [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)?)