# g++ compiling sources in UTF-16 encoding

Tags: encoding, g++

g++ does not compile my source files which are in UTF-16 encoding. Is it possible to do it or should I use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Either convert your source to UTF-8 with iconv or pass -finput-charset=UTF-16 to g++

Comment: When I type ':set fileencoding' in Vim, it shows me 'utf-16le'. Does it make sense to point utf-16le instead utf-16?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com

Comment: Ok. I found out what was wrong. All my files were in utf-8 encoding, except one, which was in utf-16le. So after I've changed encoding of that file to utf-8 it works.

Comment: gr8...some silly mistacks may take much time to resolve :) I have well exp of that :O :D