# Stray '\*' in program error when compiling

Tags: c++, eclipse

I try to understand the work from existing project from David Silver, http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Applications.html. I try to understand his code that he works on POMCP. However, when I try to import that project into Eclipse, I encounter the following problem.

[image]

[image]

I suspect this problem is related to character encoding problem with the file .*pocman.cpp and other .**.cpp files. I try to open those files with [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad) on the Windows OS. Notepad cannot read any of those files, but [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) can read them properly. I try to work with some of existing solutions for this special character problem, but I have not successfully done so.

I already have the [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) library and [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) installed.

Comment: You can choose the encoding used for a file. Check under Help->Workspace Settings. Don't remember exactly what it was.

Comment: Note the prefix of the file name `._`. On POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS) files beginning with a dot is considered *hidden* files. That together with the underscore (which is usually is not used in the beginning of file names) makes me believe that you are not supposed to include that file in the project.

Comment: Did you mean from property->resource? I already change that on to UTF-8. But there is no workspace under help tab.

Comment: .. or, indeed, *any* file inside a folder called `.MAC OS X`.

Comment: Xcode on Mac will create those files when you edit the corresponding source file. A change log I think. Skip those when compiling.

Comment: You might want to read this about ._ files http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: @BoPersson: it mist definitely is **not** part of "XCode on Mac" (an oxymoron, or is there an 'XCode on Windows' as well?). It is an integrated part of the entire Macintosh OS X file system, meant to store file metadata for non-Posix compatible data.

Comment: The link is effectively broken (it redirects to a generic page).

Comment: [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded? What is the canonical question for that? Similar: *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/)*. Related: *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*