# Converting char[] with unicode encoding to filesystem::path

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

To simplify the problem I'm trying to solve, let's say I'm trying to build an CLI that check if a path exists using `std::filesystem::exists(path)`. This `path` came from the user input.

Here's two constraint:

1. **I'm developing on Windows.**
2. I cannot use `wmain` because I don't have access to the main function (imagine the CLI is a third-party software and I'm writing a plugin to it).
3. The argc and argv will be passed to my function with the exact signature below (see the snippet code).

Here's an example code that I write:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

void my_func(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // This is the only place I can do my works...
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        bool is_exist = std::filesystem::exists(argv[1]);

        std::cout << "The path (" <<  argv[1] << ") existence is: " << is_exist << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No path defined" << std::endl;
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    my_func(argc, argv);
    return 1;
}
```

The user can use the software with the following command:

```
./a.exe path/to/my/folder/狗猫
```

Currently, rubbish is being printed on the terminal. But [from my research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line), this is not C++ problem, but rather a cmd.exe problem.

And if it is not already obvious, the above code snippet does not work even though there is a folder called 狗猫.

My guess is I have to manually convert char[] to filesystem::path somehow. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your compiler settings/flags? Since you are using g++ maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10345802/1810087) helps... what happens if you try to `cout << "狗猫";` ?

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way to get the `wchar_t *argv[]` without `wmain` (see [GetCommandLineW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew)), if you're willing to change your API slightly. Then you can construct [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) directly from that.

With `char *argv[]` you're bound to the user's [current console codepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages) and you can only hope that it supports the characters you're interested in (characters outside the codepage will get irrecoverably corrupted). For example for shift-JIS, use `chcp 932` before starting the program.

Then follow these steps:

1. Get the current console codepage with [GetConsoleCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolecp),
2. Convert the `char` string to UTF-16 with [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar),
3. Use the `wchar_t` overload to construct [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Code example:

```
const char* mbStr = argv[1];

unsigned mbCP = GetConsoleCP();
int wLen = MultiByteToWideChar(mbCP, 0, mbStr, -1, nullptr, 0);
std::wstring wStr(wLen, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar(mbCP, 0, mbStr, -1, wStr.data(), wLen);

std::filesystem::path myPath(wStr);

if (std::filesystem::exists(myPath)) {
    // . . .
}
```